# Dynamic limitTo filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm passing an parameter into a directive. It is the number that needs to be used on the `limitTo` filter for an `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="trans in transactions | limitTo:limit = limit > 0 ? limit : 100000">
```

It is possible that the directive won't need an upper limit. I could easily do what I have listed above, but I don't like the fixed upper-limit. Granted in my case it would never be hit, but it feels sloppy.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) instead of 100000:

```
<tr ng-repeat="trans in transactions | limitTo:limit = limit > 0 ? limit : 'Infinity'">
```

Angular's  [`limitTo()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2a156c2d7ec825ff184480de9aac4b0d7fbd5275/src/ng/filter/limitTo.js) even special-cases that case to make sure it's doing the right thing:

```
function limitToFilter() {
  return function(input, limit, begin) {
    if (Math.abs(Number(limit)) === Infinity) {
      limit = Number(limit);
    } else {
      limit = toInt(limit);
    }
    if (isNaN(limit)) return input;
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own filter:

```
app.filter('optionalLimitTo', function($filter) {
    function optionalLimitTo(input, optionalLimit) {
        if (optionalLimit) {
            return $filter('limitTo')(input, optionalLimit);
        }
        else {
            return input;
        }
    }
    return optionalLimitTo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is setting limit equal to array lenght.

Example: I wanted to show a paginated table with a search input and when input value is different from '', pagination should be disabled so that it can show all filtered items in the same view.

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="searchLink" placeholder="Search">
...
<tr ng-repeat="link in links | orderBy:order:reverse | startFrom: (!searchLink || '') && ((currentPage - 1) * pageSize) | limitTo: (!searchLink && pageSize) || links.length | filter:searchLink">
```